# "NoClassDefFoundError" in jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Using Jenkins 2.8, I get the error below when I run a simple Jenkins job. The Jenkins job is for just executing a shell script.

```
FATAL: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1139)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:878)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowJob.java:629)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1376)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The workflow-aggregator is not a plugin, it's part of the Pipeline plugin, there are a lot of plugins labeled Pipeline followed by API, Basic Steps, etc. but only one like this: Pipeline
A suite of plugins that lets you orchestrate automation, simple or complex. See Pipeline as Code with Jenkins for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Got the resolution for the error. 'workflow-aggregator'(Pipeline) plugin was causing the issue. Some of the dependencies were incompatible. Uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin with all its dependencies, which fixed the above issue.

Comment: I've run into the exact same problem but am unable to locate the 'workflow-aggregator' plugin anywhere in the Jenkins 2.8 Plugin Manager. Can you provide a bit more details on how to uninstall and reinstall it? Thanks!