# jenkins with clearcase ucm and visual studio 2015

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2015, version-control, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to configure Jenkins on a windows 7 machine to create a build using Visual Studio/MSbuild. We have SCM as Clearcase UCM which seems to be a bit difficult to configure right now as it needs additional rights on the system.

My question is that is it possible to prepare build on a code which has no source control?

As I tried to configure MSBuild and then in new job set the SCM to none but eventually it led to following error.

Any one having any idea how to fix this.

```
Started by user Test Application
Building in workspace C:\Users\sopzn\.jenkins\workspace\Test
FATAL: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1139)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:884)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowJob.java:621)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1376)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your installed Jenkins plugin list to see if there is an incompatibility with a no-version-control job.

For instance, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372308/6309), the ['workflow-aggregator'(Pipeline) plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator) had to be uninstalled.